# Regular expression to return number after matched string in oracle

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I have a query:

```
select ITEM_ID from system_items where id=4020;
```

I want a regular expression that takes the above query as input and matches for pattern `"id="` and returns `4020`.

Please let me know if you have any suggestions, as I have been trying with `REGEXP_SUBSTR` in `Oracle` and couldn't get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`REGEX_SUBSTR` won't allow a look-behind like `(?<=id=\s*)\d+` so I suspect you need to do this in two operations. First get `id=4020`, then strip the `id=`.

One possible way of doing that would be:

```
REGEXP_SUBSTR(REGEXP_SUBSTR(a, 'id=\s*\d+'), '\d+')
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7005d/10)

Answer (score 0):

This should do it

```
 /id=(\d+)/

id is literal match
() are used for making the capture groups
\d is more numbers 
+ ensures 1 or more
```

demo here http://rubular.com/r/GBxfhID5hS

Comment: Hi aelor, I have tried it in this way DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(REGEXP_SUBSTR('select ITEM_ID from system_items where id=4020;','/id=(\d+)/')); It doesn't give any output :(

Comment: Can you try this DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(REGEXP_SUBSTR('select ITEM_ID from system_items where id=4020;','\d+$'));

Comment: Aelor, say if the query is "select ITEM_ID from system_items where id=4020 order by field1;" still this could work ?

Comment: i think you need to remove the start and end '/' in my regex